# How to search the pre and post part of the word using Thinking_sphinx gem on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, thinking-sphinx

I have created my search part successfully with the thinking_sphinx gem and I have searched a word it is showing correct, But the problem with the search is it need full word to be given to search exact match. I dont want to give exact word instead any particular character or part of words also be taken into account. help me to solve this problem..

example

```
say my word is "Sample"
```

instead of giving sample i need to specify part of the word like.

```
amp or ple
```

for rails code we will specify

```
find :all, :conditions => ["user_id like ? ", "%#{search}%"]
```

how to specify this, by using thinking_sphinx gem.

i tried with,

```
  User.search "*amp*"
```

but of no result guide me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the Result,

At first I have added

```
development:
      enable_star: 1
      min_infix_len: 3
```

on config -> sphinx.yml

and I have rebuild my application by using

```
rake ts:rebuild
```

and then on controller,

```
User.search "*mple", :star => true
```

which result,

```
sample
```

Comment: You should only have either infix _or_ prefix - Sphinx doesn't like it if you use both. In your case, you'll want infix - which includes prefixes and suffixes.